# Pickle module that breaks the code from the book "Conceptual Programming with Python"

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, pickle

I'm taking the example from the book "Conceptual Programming with Python".

Some introduction to the problem that the code is aimed at solving:

**Example: Creating a Knowledge Base**

*As a second example for OOP, we are going to implement a simple guessing game! But this game will be able to learn from experience, that is, you will be able to teach the program as you play. For this example, we will create a knowledge base of animals. The user will think of an animal, and the computer will have to figure out which animal it is by asking you (sensible) questions about that animal; the answer will be either yes or no. If it fails to guess correctly the animal, the program will ask you what would be a sensible question to be able to find the right solution next time!*

***Example 1: The computer only knows how to distinguish between a bird or a cat depending on whether it has 4 legs or not. That is, the initial knowledge base only contains these two animals and one single question.***

- *You: Think of a cat.*
- *Computer: Does it have 4 legs?*
- *You: Yes*
- *Computer: Were you thinking of a cat?*
- *You: Yes*
- *Computer: I knew it !! Let's keep playing! I am good at this!*

*Once again, this follows a tree structure! Depending on whether the user answers yes or no, the computer will ask a different question, or will provide an answer!*

***Example 2: You teach the computer a new question.***

- *You: Think of a dog.*
- *Computer: Does it have 4 legs?*
- *You: Yes*
- *Computer: Were you thinking of a cat?*
- *You: No*
- *Computer: What animal were you thinking of?*
- *You: Dog*
- *Computer: What is a question to distinguish between dog and cat?*
- *You: Does it bark?*
- *Computer: For a dog, what should be the answer?*
- *You: Yes*

Now for the ***pickle*** fragment:

*Files need to be always opened first; then manipulate them (for example loading their content into a data structure), and finally close them when they are no longer in use. So, we are going to try to open a file called animal.kb in which we will save the tree. The first time we open the file, it will be empty, so we will create our previous knowledge base. To do so, we will use a try-except structure. Why? Whenever we try to open a file that doesn’t exist, this will create an exception FileNotFoundError. We can simply catch it and create the knowledge base ‘manually’. Then we let the user play, and we keep updating the knowledge base kb. At the end of the program, when the user doesn’t want to play anymore, we ‘dump’ the information contained in kb on the file “animal.kb”.*

After the 2nd try with opening the "animal.kb" knowledge base the error appears:

````
```

Do you want to play? y
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "...\ConceptualPython02\knowledgeBase.py", line 71, in <module>
        kb = kb.play()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'
    
    Process finished with exit code 1

```
````

***That's the problematic code:***

```
    import pickle


    class Knowledge:
        pass
    
    
    class Question(Knowledge):
        def __init__(self, text, if_yes, if_no):
            self.text, self.if_yes, self.if_no = text, if_yes, if_no
    
        def play(self):
            if ask(self.text):
                self.if_yes = self.if_yes.play()
            else:
                self.if_no = self.if_no.play()
                return self
    
    
    class Answer(Knowledge):
        def __init__(self, text):
            self.text = text
    
        def play(self):
            if ask("Were you thinking of a {} ? ".format(self.text)):
                print("I knew it!")
                return self
            # here we got it right, # so we simply return the
            # Answer node as it is.
            else:
                newanimal = input("What animal were\ "
                                  "you thinking of? ")
                newquestion = input("What is a question "
                                    "to distinguish between {} and {} ?"
                                    .format(self.text, newanimal))
                # but in case we didn't know the animal
                # we need to modify the node adding # the appropriate question and# what to do
                # ifyes and if no
                if ask("For {} , what should be the answer? ".format(newanimal)):
                    return Question(newquestion,
                                    Answer(newanimal), self)
                else:
                    return Question(newquestion,
                                    self, Answer(newanimal))
    
    
    def ask(q):
        while True:
            ans = input(q + " ")
            if ans == "y":
                return True
            elif ans == "n":
                return False
            else:
                print("Please answer y or n!")
    
    
    try:
        file = open("animal.kb", "rb")
        kb = pickle.load(file)
        file.close()
    
    except FileNotFoundError:
        kb = Question("Does it have 4 legs?", Question("Does it bark?",
                                                       Answer("dog"), Answer("cat")), Answer("bird"))
    while True:
        if not ask("Do you want to play?"):
            break
        kb = kb.play()
    
    file = open("animal.kb", "wb")
    pickle.dump(kb, file)
    file.close()
```

Of course, also, it doesn't cache the new questions about the animals as it should have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`play` should always return a `Knowledge` instance (or inherited from it). But when in `Question.play` the call to `ask` returns `True`, you don't return anything:

```
        def play(self):
            if ask(self.text):
                self.if_yes = self.if_yes.play()
            else:
                self.if_no = self.if_no.play()
                return self
```

So change the indentation of `return self` so it is always executed.

Comment: I've changed the indentation and it still runs into the same error. I've also added return self at the if block on the second trial ... and it still runs at the same error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. So I will delete my answer.